# Restore Lion on MacBook with Sierra on it

Tags: macos, restore

I have a MacBook 10,7 with macOS Sierra installed. I want to return to Lion; that was its default OS, but I have no backup from Lion. What to do now?

Comment: Would Mountain Lion be an option as well?

Answer (score 1):

While ignoring this is not such a good idea security-wise, you can only downgrade a macOS with an external medium (Disc, USB-Stick) while erasing your hard drive completely.

- Since you no longer own a copy of Lion,
  you need to buy it in the Apple Store: [Link](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion)
- You also need a USB Stick with 8GB of Space

---

1. Purchase the Copy of Lion from the Apple Store
2. Redeem your code in the Mac App Store
3. Download your copy of Lion, you will see a "Install Mac OS X Lion" in your Applications folder.
4. Download [DiskMakerX](http://diskmakerx.com/) aka LionDiskMaker
5. Point it to your Copy of Lion and your 8GB Stick
6. After finishing restart your mac and press <kbd>alt</kbd> as soon as the screen flashes
7. Start the USB Stick (Lion Installer)
8. Open Disk Utility in Menu --> Utilities and erase your hard drive
9. Install OS X Lion
10. Be happy with your old OS